# Suddenly all my files have a null kMDItemDateAdded (Date Added) field

Tags: mac, macos

Almost all my files now have a null kMDItemDateAdded field:

```
$ mdls -name kMDItemFSName -name kMDItemDateAdded 2014-01-14-1500595479_04-EVN.PDF
kMDItemDateAdded = (null)
kMDItemFSName    = "2014-01-14-1500595479_04-EVN.PDF"
```

How could it happen? What do I need to do to restore it?

Comment: This seems to be a Yosemite bug, I've had iCloud files revert to 2001 because of this. Did you install 10.10.1?

Comment: I'm still on 10.10. Do you think 10.10.1 would fix it?

Comment: Suddenly I realized that I have tried turning off spotlight like mentioned here [http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144474/mds-and-mds-stores-constantly-consuming-cpu] and may be I have turned it back on only after couple of days.

Comment: I think so, I haven't seen the iCloud issue after the update. The bug is actually in Finder on the MAC. I think it happen system wide but I never noticed it until I opened something from iCloud, I have "sort by date added" on that and every time I opened a file it went back to 2001.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its a bug. An update in Apples mdimport schema will cause this. I checked this file /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Resources/MetadataSchema.xsd on OSX 10.6.8 and OSX 10.9 and found `kMDItemDateAdded` only in `10.9`.

When your mdworker will update your existing Meta Data using the new schema, it will fill `kMDItemDateAdded` with `null`, because `PDF.mdimporter` is not taking care of this attribute. How should the pdf know, when it is added?

If your `mds` is consuming lots of CPU time ou should re-index your Spotlight Database like mentioned [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162227/how-to-isolate-processes-that-evoke-insane-mds-stores-disk-read-activity/191503#191503)