# `mds_stores` jump very high for a while

Tags: macos

[image]

When I edit a web page in `safari`. with opened `visual studio code` a moment ago, and didn't close it.

The cpu just jump higher, so I close that web page and visual studio code, then the cpu jump down to normal.  Not sure what case this.

I have notice that the `mds` is lower when the `mds_stores` are high.

PS: it's `macOS 10.15.1`

### Edit:

I didn't think it's duplicate of another question [mds-and-mds-stores-constantly-consuming-cpu](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144474/mds-and-mds-stores-constantly-consuming-cpu), because in that question, the situation is

- lower cpu consumer: mds:`11.9%`, mds_stores:`9.6`,
- compare to mine:    mds:`1.3`, mds_stores:`701.8`(kind of killing my cpu)
- the cpu drop down to normal after I close the webpage & vscode.

Comment: I have check that question too, but it's about spotlight,  in my case I was editing some text in a webpage within safari.  I didn't use spotlight to search things, but also I didn't disable it.    And his case only have `11%`, mine is `700%`. huge different. I was afraid my computer killed by this..

Comment: the other answer document what the process is about. Comments and other answers tell how people caught their culprits. To me, it looks like VSCode and you can try excluding your working directory from the index.

Comment: `sudo mdutil -a -i off` you can run this command to disable the indexing of Spotlight. `sudo mdutil -a -i on` to put it back on. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144474/mds-and-mds-stores-constantly-consuming-cpu

Comment: @PhilippeRemy thank you,  I can have a try next time.