# msd_stores consuming twice the amount of memory than I have available on my mac

Tags: memory, spotlight, performance

[image: There's only 16GB RAM on this computer]

There's only 16Gb of RAM on this computer (quad-core 15" Macbook Pro) but Activity Monitor is saying mds_store is using 32Gb. Rendering in Sublime and Brave browser when I scroll and type was lagging considerably. It's been indexing for at least the last two days.

`sudo mdutil -a -i off` slowed the fan speed but the lag still persists, and Activity Monitory memory is still at 32Gb.

After that, I run `sudo fs_usage -w -f filesys mds_stores` and I get a lot of Backup and Sync and Brave Browser with `/dev/disk1s4  /System/Volumes/VM/swapfile0`. I quit Backup and Sync (using Brave to write this) and there's still no change to performance or memory.

Also, after upgrading to Big Sur, Spotlight  basically useless since it's so slow.

Comment: How long ago did you update to Big Sur? mds_stores **is** Spotlight, and will have to run across the entire Mac immediately after a major update. This may take some time & the Mac will run slowly until it completes. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144474/mds-and-mds-stores-constantly-consuming-cpu

Comment: I think I updated immediately after Big Sur was out of beta; it was quite a while ago. Thanks for the link, I've seen the comments and that's where I got the commands I used above. (also the OP's mds_store is in mb, whereas mine is in Gb).

Comment: Big Sur was released November last year - if it's been a problem for that long, then mds really ought to have finished its initial update long ago ;)

Comment: Ive had a similar thing with large word documents (~40 MB). Word becomes almost unusable and uses 40 or so GB of ram when i only have 24 GB. I suspect that this is including swap usage.